# How to get Local Area Connection Name with batch script in windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a simple batch script to retrieve all the network interfaces on Windows. But I only need the Local Area Connection name. Local Area Connection interface name is not default. Is there any way to retrieve only Local Area connection name as string with a batch script?

Comment: As a starter you can use the [WMIC tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394531) to query for information.

Comment: or possibly ipconfig depending on what you're looking for, but my question is are you looking for the DNS name of the domain? or the title of the actual connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not completely sure what you are asking, but I assume your question is you want to get all the friendly names of the network interfaces.

Something like this:

```
wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get netconnectionid
```

which returns (on my laptop)

```
NetConnectionID
Local Area Connection
Wireless Network Connection
Bluetooth Network Connection
VirtualBox Host-Only Network
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer, I hope you get a green check for it.

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('NetSh Interface IPv4 Show Interfaces') DO echo %%i this command execute properly but above command which you suggested to me didnt execute. instead of this i used 'wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get netconnectionid' but an exception occured. have you any suggestions for this? you can try both commands on your side than you will understand better.

Comment: probably i will be need the correct escape character to execute this command.

Comment: Try from within a .cmd file: FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('NetSh.exe Interface IP Show Interface') DO echo %%i

Answer (score 3):

For just the one actively connected now:

```
C:\>wmic.exe nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID |more +1
Local Area Connection 8
```

To understand the above better, try:

```
C:\>wmic.exe nic > 1.txt

C:\>1.txt
```