# How do I retrieve the name of the currently connected wireless network in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I can't seem to find this question anywhere else, but, how do I retrieve the name of the currently connected wireless network. If it's necessary, my aim of the program is to disconnect from the internet for 10 seconds, then to reconnect. Here's my code:

```bat
@echo off
ipconfig /release
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
netsh wlan connect %Network%
```

I just need help getting the exact name of the wireless network that I am currently connected to, to fit in `%Network%`. I'd like any help.

I'm also a beginner in batch so yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get network information use [`netsh wlan show interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755301(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#bkmk_wlanShowInterfaces). You can further filter the interface out with `name=`. In the output SSID will be in the `SSID` field and probably also `Profile` field which can be extracted with [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html). Data can then be read into a variable with [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

```bat
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%n in ('netsh wlan show interface name="Wi-Fi" ^| findstr "SSID"') do set "Network=%%n"
set "Network=%Network:~1%"
```

The last line is for removing the first space character using [variable substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Of course this assumes you have only one WLAN adapter. If you have more than one then things are more complicated and you have several choices

- go out of the loop early like the other answer to get the first result
- do nothing to get the last result
- do things with each adapter inside the loop to get all information about them

Another option is to use

```bat
netsh wlan show networks interface="Wi-Fi" mode=ssid
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked, I just need to change `"SSID"` to `"Profile"`to return the SSID, because instead of showing SSID, it showed part of BSSID.

Comment: @William. Refering to your comment above. To get the SSID and not the BSSID I've found that you can also change your findstr FROM findstr "SSID" TO  findstr ^/R "\<SSID".

Answer (score -1):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151739/6707985) and modified:

As you can find in linked answer, the general command to get the information you want is `wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID`. With `| more +1` you can pass the header that would be displayed in the wmic-command alone.

To get this into a variable you want to parse the output of that command with `for /f`:

```
for /f %%n in ('wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID ^| more +1') do (
  set "Network=%%n"
  goto outer
)
:outer
```

I use the goto to exit the loop on the first iteration and only use it to parse the first line. As the output of the command contains some empty lines this would then leave you with an empty variable if the label would not be there.

Comment: doesn't work in my PC. `wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID` outputs `NetConnectionID
VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
Wi-Fi` and no network name is available